# Issues with path for java.io.File

Tags: java, xml, swt

I am getting file path in eclipse plugin using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog` and saving the path in XML files.

In web.xml , path is stored as below (I can't change backsladh to forwardslash or escape backslash since the value is coming from SWT FileDialog)

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>filePath</param-name>
  <param-value>c:\new\demo\next\version.txt</param-value>
</init-param>
```

In my filter , i have below code in init() method but am not able to get File reference due to special characters

```
String filePath = filterConfig.getInitParameter("filePath");
// Tried filePath.replace('\\','/') --> Didnot work since \n is a single character
File f = new File(path)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting file path in eclipse plugin using
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog and saving the path in XML files.
>
> In web.xml , path is stored as below (I can't change backsladh to
>   forwardslash or escape backslash since the value is coming from SWT
>   FileDialog)

The SWT File Dialog does not write web.xml files. You are doing that, so you *can* fix the backslashes. Change them to forward slashes.

> I have below code in init() method but am not able to get File
>   reference due to special characters
>   that did not work because \n is considered a single character [from one of your comments]

That implies that the data is wrong *in the web.xml file.* Nothing you can do in code can fix that. This is not a coding question. You don't need to process backslashes in Java. The compiler already does that, and so in this case did the XML parser in the web-app container. You need to get the file format correct up front.

Comment: Thanks @EJP , igot it working now and since yours solution is exactly what is required , accepted it as answer

Answer (score 2):

> i could not get the actual path since \n is considered as new line.

That suggests that whatever's reading the file is assuming escaping which simply isn't the case.

Unfortunately, you haven't told us what code is used to *write* the data *or* the code used to *read* the data. Is it under your control in either path?

Basically you need to be escaping in the same way as you unescape - so either you can escape `c:\new\demo\next\version.txt` to `c:\\new\\demo\\next\\version.txt` when you're writing the data, or you can remove the code which tries to unescape when you're reading the data.

Note that if you *literally* tried:

```
string.replace('\\', '/');
```

then that certainly won't help at all - as you're ignoring the return value. If you tried

```
string = string.replace('\\', '/');
```

then that should have performed the relevant replacements, but you didn't say *where* you were trying to do that, or in what *way* it didn't work.

I would actually treat the forward vs back-slashes as a red herring here: fundamentally you need to escape in the same way as you unescape. Replacing backslashes with forward slashes may help for filenames, but you'll just get problems elsewhere in cases where you *can't* just perform that replacement.

Comment: In web.xml , path is stored as below (I can't change backslash to forwardslash or escape backslash since the value is coming from SWT FileDialog)\n <init-param> <param-name>filePath</param-name> <param-value>c:\new\demo\next\version.txt</param-value> </init-param> \n In my filter , i have below code in init() method but am not able to get File reference due to special characters String filePath = filterConfig.getInitParameter("filePath"); // Tried filePath.replace('\\','/') --> Didnot work since \n is a single character File f = new File(path)

Comment: String.replace i didn't ignore return value , that didnot work because \n is considered a single character